# Consulta total de dados cadastrados em um campo

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela onde é definido um campo do país. Eu quero saber como eu posso desenvolver uma consulta que me mostre quantos registos tenho para cada país.

Exemplo:

> Brasil: 10 registros
>  EUA: 5 registros

Comment: @user3163662 Você pode usar o COUNT para contar os resultados do campo. Exemplo: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cadastro_cliente WHERE pais = "Brasil"`

Comment: Sim, mas isso no caso seria para determinado pais, como essa tabela é o lugar onde guardo estatísticas de acesso.. Nao daria muito certo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meio vago mas algo como

```
Select pais,count(*) qtd
From tabela
Group by pais
```

Comment: Hey! Obrigado, conseguir me orientar com isso e responder outras duvidas!

Comment: @user3163662, confira [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/201) ;)